# Radio button selected value is not getting reflected in command button ajax call

Tags: jsf-2

I have an issue with radio button. i have a 2 set of radio buttons and one command button  in a field set.Based on the selection of radio button, respected value will be displayed through ajax call. But issue is always the first button is gettting considred in the command button action, thats why always first values is getting displayed,however the second radio button is selected.Here is my code

//test.xhtml

```
    <h:panelGroup id="demandDashBoardPanelGroupID">
    <fieldset> 
    <legend style="font-family:Arial;font-size: 12px;">Demand Dashboard</legend>

     <table>
        <tr>
        <td> 
            <h:selectOneRadio immediate="true" id="groupbyid" value="#{demandManagedBean.selectedRadioButton}" styleClass="labelstyle">  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Group By Creation Date Time" itemValue="1" />  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Group By Location" itemValue="2" />
            </h:selectOneRadio>
        </td>
        <td>

            <h:commandButton id="fetchbuttonID" value="Fetch" 
                    style="font-size:13px;width:60px;height:25px;" action="#{demandManagedBean.displayDemandRequestsTable}">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{demandManagedBean.selectedRadioButtonParam}" value="#{demandManagedBean.selectedRadioButton}"/>
                    <f:ajax render=":parentformid:demandrequestpanelgrpid" immediate="true"/> 
            </h:commandButton>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>

     </fieldset>

     </h:panelGroup>

    <h:panelGroup id="demandrequestpanelgrpid" rendered="#{demandManagedBean.renderedFieldSet}"> 

     <fieldset id="demandrequestfieldsetid"> 

     <legend style="font-family:Arial;font-size: 12px;">Demand Requests</legend>

            <h:outputText rendered="#{demandManagedBean.renderCreationdateDmdtable}" value="first table"/>

            <h:outputText rendered="#{demandManagedBean.renderDmdLocationTable}" value="second table"/>

     </fieldset> 

   </h:panelGroup>
```

//backing bean action

```
public void displayDemandRequestsTable(){


        if(selectedRadioButtonParam!= null && selectedRadioButtonParam.endsWith("1")){

            renderCreationdateDmdtable = true;
            renderDmdLocationTable = false;

        }else if(selectedRadioButtonParam!= null && selectedRadioButtonParam.endsWith("2")){

            renderCreationdateDmdtable = false;
            renderDmdLocationTable = true;

        }
        renderedFieldSet = true;
    }
```

Comment: What is the scope of your backing bean? How are the boolean values initialized? (Presumably radio button on is default?). Btw you don't need the f:setPropertyActionListener. The value should be set if you submit the form and have `execute="groupbyid"` in your ajax tag.

Comment: Scope of backing bean is session and these radio value at backing bean is being set as private String selectedRadioButton = "1" and it has setter and getter methods.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `f:setPropertyActionListener` here to get the selected value into your backing bean. Just add an `execute` attribute to your `f:ajax` tag and remove the `immediate=true`:

```html
<h:commandButton ...>
   <f:ajax render=":parentformid:demandrequestpanelgrpid" execute="@form" /> 
</h:commandButton>
```

You could also just give the id of the component to be executed instead of the whole form:

```
<h:commandButton ...>
   <f:ajax render=":parentformid:demandrequestpanelgrpid" execute="groupbyid" /> 
</h:commandButton>
```

Also make sure that the `selectedRadioButton` is properly initialized in your backing bean and that the bean is at least in `@ViewScoped`.

UPDATE:
If you remove the `f:setPropertyActionListener` then the `selectedRadioButtonParam` will not be set. Then you need to check `selectedRadioButton` inside your action method instead.

Comment: Thank for u r reply Handy, i have tried this approch also , eventhough not working.<h:commandButton id="fetchbuttonID" value="Fetch" 
        style="font-size:13px;width:60px;height:25px;" action="#{demandManagedBean.displayDemandRequestsTable}">
        <f:ajax execute="groupbyid" render=":parentformid:demandrequestpanelgrpid" /> 
      </h:commandButton>

Comment: Ok, did you change the action method that it doesn't check `selectedRadioButtonParam` (value is not set without the setPropertyActionListener) but `selectedRadioButton` instead? Can you verify with a debugger that `selectedRadioButton` has the correct value inside the action method?

Comment: yeah i have changed selectedRadioButtonParam  to selectedRadioButton in method also. everytime it is having the same default value..that is "1" even if option 2 is selected.

Comment: You are welcome. Since you are new here, please don't forget to mark my answer as "accepted" (click on the hook on the left side of the answer).

Comment: Handy, i observed onething , at first time page loads, and when fetch button is clicked, nothing is happening (but the method action method is getting called). but when i refresh the page, that movement, based on the selection the respective text is getting printed. Why is this strange behaviour?? can you please help me out?

Comment: Then your render attribute does not work correctly. Try `render="@form"`

Comment: Actually <h:panelGroup id="demandrequestpanelgrpid" rendered="#{demandManagedBean.renderedFieldSet}">  tag is getting displayed based on the renderedFieldSet attribute. This attribute is getting changed in the command button action, when we click.At first time when page loads this attribute is getting set as false, so that i wont display anything.when i clik the fetch button,then the action method for this btn is getting called and setting renderedFieldSet attribute to true. But the issue is renderedFieldSet attribute is not getting set even we click the fetch button after page load.